# Windows 10 Enterprise (version 1607) cannot click bottom half of the screen

Tags: windows-10, display, vmware-workstation, windows-10-v1607, mouse-click

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise (version 1607) on VMWare Workstation 12.5. Since the last Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1607 for x64-based Systems (KB4022715), I am experiencing a strange problem. I can not click on any links, menu that is situated in the bottom half of my screen.

At first I thought it was infamous windows 10 menu problem,however, when I transferred my menu bar at the top of the screen, I have no problem whatsoever. The problem lies in the bottom half of the screen. I simply cannot click on anything that is situated on the bottom half of my screen. It looks like as if click is disabled. I have to use my keyboard arrows button to navigate and use Enter button to click! I tried changing usb mouse, it did not help either. Tried to restart explorer without success, restart computer several times without success. The update was installed successfully on second attempt.

Is there anyone who have had similar problem?

Comment: Does this happen if you are on desktop only, or also in another program, such as Excel? Does this happens on safe mode?

Comment: I think I found the reason. When I was trying to re-confirm your comment about host machine (desktop), I found that my left screen has no problem (where my host machine is), however, I work on virtual machine with both screen. I use all the application that I type on right hand screen and left one is for reading(mostly). Therefore, I never noticed that my left screen is working perfectly. I think it could be problem with my right screen.

Comment: Try switching "reading" to your right and see if the problem still there

Comment: Restarting both host and virtual machine as well as disconnecting the right monitor for a while fixed my problem. I had the problem for two days! Cannot pint point the problem, that is frustrating. Anyway, it solved the problem. And, my left monitor had no problem, it was only the right one.